# how to print a value with items in a dictionary if a dict value equals a number?

Tags: python, dictionary, operators

I have this code which checks if a value is less than/equal to (etc) my number limit. Which works as desired and prints out the corresponding keys and values which match these operator checks. But I also want it to print one of two categories they each fall into having matched the operator checks, as a string anything which works as long as it shows which category that puts them into. I know how to do this for lists and better with R, but not as sure with dictionaries in python how to achieve this.

This is my code to reproduce to what I have done--

Create the dictionary:

```
d = {'Tony':5, 'Mary':7.8, 'Joe':8.9,'Lee':6.8, 'Luke':11.5, 'Sally':5.8,'Billy':15.2, 'Josè':11.1, 'Jesus':18.9,'Frank':10.5}
```

Check the values:

```
lessthn = {k:v for (k,v) in d.items() if v  < 10.9 }

morethneqlto = {k:v for (k,v) in d.items() if v  >= 10.9 }
```

Outcome example (I just made this up now to show what the outcome is like - this doesn't match the dictionary values I created):

```
{'Tony': 6,
 'Sally': 5.8,
 'Mary': 7.9,
 'Billy': 9.8,
 'John': 2.8,
 'Joe': 9.5}


{'Luke': 16,
 'Amy': 15.8,
 'Gillan': 17.9,
 'Sandra': 19.8,
 'Jesus': 12.8,
 'Josè': 19.5}
```

Desired outcome to put it next to each matched value, something like this or whatever is possible :

```
{'Tony': 6 : Good,
 'Sally': 5.8 : Good,
 'Mary': 7.9 : Good,
 'Billy': 9.8 : Good,
 'John': 2.8 : Good,
 'Joe': 9.5 : Good}



{'Luke': 6 : Bad,
 'Amy': 5.8 : Bad,
 'Gillan': 7.9 : Bad,
 'Sandra': 9.8 : Bad,
 'Jesus': 2.8 : Bad,
 'Josè': 9.5 : Bad}
```

I had a crack at what the answer could be but had no luck, I tried things such as this:

```
morethaneqlto.append('Bad')
```

But append doesnt work with dict

and something like this, but I know this isn't right and think there is likely a more simple solution out there:

```
if < 11.1 d.values:
    print ("Good")
```

Any solution that would make my output something along the lines of the desired output would be amazing

Comment: Your desired outcome is not legal Python.  The `if` thing you wrote is unclear, as it is also does not make sense in either Python or basic algebraic expression.  At this point, you need to return to your materials and learn more about the data structures and language so that you can ask a clear question.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials; this is your task.

Comment: I am only new python, I'm sorry my approach isn't as good as it could be. I am trying my best and I am only learning currently. Hence my simple questions, I do use the documentation, use books, check google and I several courses on Udemy. Sorry if my question bothered you and my lack of knowledge. We all start somewhere. Thank you for the advice. I will review my material further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pandas` to create a `DataFrame` that conditionally labels each entry based on the corresponding value

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = {'Tony':5, 'Mary':7.8, 'Joe':8.9,'Lee':6.8, 'Luke':11.5, 'Patient6':5.8,'Patient7':15.2, 'Josè':11.1, 'Jesus':18.9,'Frank':10.5}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': d.keys(), 'Value': d.values()})
>>> df['Label'] = np.where(df['Value'] > 10, 'Good', 'Bad')
>>> df
      Names  Value Label
0      Tony    5.0   Bad
1      Mary    7.8   Bad
2       Joe    8.9   Bad
3       Lee    6.8   Bad
4      Luke   11.5  Good
5  Patient6    5.8   Bad
6  Patient7   15.2  Good
7      Josè   11.1  Good
8     Jesus   18.9  Good
9     Frank   10.5  Good
```

Comment: that is perfect thank you so much friend!

Answer (score 1):

The value in a dictionary has to be a single object. If you want both the number and the indicator, you have to put them in a single object. For instance,

```
lessthn = {k:(v,"Good") for (k,v) in d.items() if v  < 11.1 }
```